# Using multiple threads for a single process collectively

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, cpu-usage

I have a factorial program I wrote as a benchmark test, It takes 3 minutes to calculate the factorial of 1 million with a single thread. I’m curious if it is possible to allocate multiple threads to the same algorithm, not running concurrently, but collectively thus increasing the processing speed and decreasing the time it takes to run the algorithm. I’m assuming it is possible because supercomputers have many threads, and normally average CPU frequencies.

Comment: To make use of multithread, you need a way to break down your algorithm into module which can be execute parallely

Comment: you can used stream.

Comment: see this link http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams @Bailey Danseglio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex mentioned, this problem can be easily spread across multiple threads.

Let's see a single-threaded implementation using Java8 streams:

```
Stream<BigInteger> numbers = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 1_000_000).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf);
BigInteger reduced = numbers.reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
```

Now let's look at a multi-threaded version of the same:

```
Stream<BigInteger> numbers = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 1_000_000).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf);
numbers = numbers.parallel();
BigInteger reduced = numbers.reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
```

(Yes, the only difference is `numbers = numbers.parallel();` - the beauty of streams)

The second one is *much* faster than the first one (depending on the number of real and hyperthreading CPU's that you have), but gets the same outcome.

---

For some reason that I cannot fully explain yet, the parallel version is *much* faster than the non-parallel version. It probably has to do with memory usage. On my 4-core 2.5Ghz i7 MacBook Pro, it takes 5.8 seconds to compute with the parallel version, but the non-parallel version doesn't complete even in 10 minutes (for 1 million).

For 100,000 the parallel version is much faster: 90 milliseconds for parallel version 2500 milliseconds for non-parallel (measured 10th iteration after 9 warmup iterations).

Comment: The parallel version takes a little under 4 seconds on my 20-core workstation, but the non-parallel version apparently chooses to realize the entire list of `BigInteger`s before reducing and so takes around 4 _minutes_.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if you have `k` processors, you can split the work for `n` factorial into finding the products of `[2, n * (1/k)], ... [n * ((k-1)/k) + 1, n]` in parallel to get numbers `P_1, ..., P_k`, then the overall factorial is `n! = P_1 * ... * P_k`.